# I really need help to not let my parents get a divorce

Tags: parents, divorce, fighting

I'm 13 and yes, I know I'm young and don't understand marriage and stuff, but I can't let my parents get a divorce, my mom is the only one who has mentioned wanting a divorce ever, my dad at least wants to some how work it out, they are always fighting about the dumbest things, they are both just so head strong, neither of them wants to even listen to the other persons side, when ever they fight, it's like hours of literal yelling and screaming at each other,some times, they have even gone so far as to hit each other before,  the neighbors think we are crazy, my mom is a house mom, no job, my dad go's on 3-5 day work trips around the area making our money, I have 3 other siblings,  2 younger brothers and a 18 year old sister who moved out last year, and I know that when they aren't fighting about stupid stuff, they absolutely love each other, you can tell from just the way they look at each other, but then the fighting starts and they turn into completely different people... please help me to get them to stop and use some common sense...

Comment: I've linked your question to another person asking the same thing; their question has a lot of good answers. Unfortunately though, there is likely not an awful lot you can do about this.